# Error when creating a Subversion tag using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tagging

Subversion 1.7.8 has been installed in a server running Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 2.
Subversion runs as a Windows service.
Directory d:\SvnRepositories has been created on the server to store the repositories.

TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 has been installed on the server.
Using TortoiseSVN, a repository has been created for project TEST:
d:\SvnRepositories\TEST

Directory source has been created under TEST:
d:\SvnRepositories\TEST\source

Directories branches, tags and trunk have been created under source:
d:\SvnRepositories\TEST\source\branches
d:\SvnRepositories\TEST\source\tags
d:\SvnRepositories\TEST\source\trunk

---

On a client computer, which runs Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3, TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 has been installed as well.
Using TortoiseSVN > Import, the source code of project TEST, stored on the client computer, has been loaded into the repository on the server.

On the same client computer, a working directory has been created:
C:\Svn

Directory TEST has been created under Svn:
C:\Svn\TEST

Using TortoiseSVN > Checkout, files have been checked out to C:\Svn\TEST from the following server location:
svn://///d:/SvnRepositories/TEST/source/trunk

---

On the client computer, working directory, TortoiseSVN > Branch/tag has been selected.
In the Copy (Branch / Tag) dialog box, the following fields have been filled:
- To path: /source/tags/version-5.6.1
- Log message: Creation of version 5.6.1
- Create copy in the repository from: Specific revision in repository
- Revision: 1
- Switch working copy to new brach/tag: checked

After clicking OK and providing my credentials, the following error message is displayed:
**File not found: transaction '1-1', path '/source/tags/version-5.6.1'**

Are the server and client properly configured?
What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

PTM

Comment: Is `d:\SvnRepositories\TEST\source` a directory you can see in Windows Explorer, or is `source` a directory that you've created within the repository?

Comment: The mentioned directory was created via Windows Explorer.

Comment: Then it is not in your repository. Once you create the repository, anything that is to be accessed in it must be created via Subversion, not as a child item (file, directory) in Explorer. You really need to go back to the manual, read it, and understand how to use Subversion & how the repository works. Start at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-qs-guide.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, alroc. After following the instructions you suggested, the problem was solved. As a novice user of Subversion, I did follow instructions in my first attempt, but, evidently, they were not correct.

Comment: @PTM: You should consider posting the solution as an answer and accept it so that other users know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating @alroc answer:

The repository needs to be created using the <kbd>TortoiseSVN</kbd> > <kbd>Create Repository Here...</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I later found that the svn password stored for svn communications was outdated. Once I updated the password, the error went away and everything worked fine.